# Why python plotly box-plot y axis is not showing?

Tags: python, data-visualization, boxplot, plotly-python

I am trying to plot a boxplot though every other data in the plot is showing as expected. But the y-axis is not showing the scale instead showing some disfigured lines as in the image:                            [image]

Here is my code for same please help me sort it out:

```
`traces=[]
traces.append(go.Box(
            y=nasdaq['market_cap_m'],
            x=nasdaq['Sector'],
            notched=True, # used notched shape

            boxpoints='all',
            jitter=0.5,
            whiskerwidth=0.2,
            marker_color='rgb(7,40,89)',
    line_color='rgb(7,40,89)',
    marker=dict(
        color='rgb(8,81,156)',
        outliercolor='rgba(219, 64, 82, 0.6)',
        line=dict(
            outliercolor='rgba(219, 64, 82, 0.6)',
            outlierwidth=2))
    
        ))
layout = go.Layout(
    title='Boxplot Showing Quartiles and Outliers in Different Sectors',
    yaxis=dict(
        autorange=True,
        showgrid=True,
        zeroline=True,
        dtick=5,
        gridcolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        gridwidth=1,
        zerolinecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        zerolinewidth=2,
    ),
    margin=dict(
        l=40,
        r=30,
        b=80,
        t=100,
    ),
    paper_bgcolor='rgb(243, 243, 243)',
    plot_bgcolor='rgb(243, 243, 243)',
    showlegend=False
)
fig = go.Figure(data=traces, layout=layout)
fig.show(renderer="colab")`
```

Trying to figure out the issue here but I guess my eyes couldn't find the solutions. So here I am to take help from some of the very awesome people on StackOverflow.Thanks in Advances.

Comment: One of the things to check is that the y-axis value is a number, not a string. Then if it is a number, you can set autorange=False and set the range to improve it or second. Once the data is presented, the issue can be determined.

Comment: @r-beginners  yes it numbers only I already tried the trick you mentioned showing the same plot as above.No change not showing any error also.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data so that I can try it in my environment?

Comment: The data you provided was incomplete and I was unable to reproduce all of it. However, I was able to confirm the same issue. I found an equivalent sample in the official reference, so I checked the data structure and found that the data reference was different from your code, so I got the industry classification and drew a box plot with data extraction for each. I also thought that the size of the y-axis value might have an effect, so I made the y-axis value smaller. We did not try using integer values for the y-axis.

Comment: @r-beginners you can delete this I think you are right there may be an issue with  plotly side regarding bigger values I am thinking to report it I tried converting to integers since I am too following the official doc. but it still not working and smaller values are showing the y-axis but boxplot is not missing

Comment: for some shapes are showing but it's not notched

Comment: I hope you will report your issues and that they will improve.

Comment: @r- beginners thanks for being of great help on stack overflow i really appreciate your efforts to help in solving problems here keep up the good work...!!